# Listing database names from multiple databases that a user has access to

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I was asked by my supervisor to create an ssrs report (using sql server 2008)that will display all the database names that a user has access to and making sure that the user still has an active account. I can query user names from different databases but I can't seem to list database names that a user has access to.

Is there a way to achieve this eventhough some databases are located in a different linked server.

Thank you everyone in advance, any help to point me to right direction is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @DBuser_table TABLE (DBName VARCHAR(200), 
        UserName VARCHAR(250), 
        LoginType VARCHAR(500), 
        AssociatedRole VARCHAR(200)) 
DECLARE @UserName VARCHAR(250)

SET @UserName = 'dbo' --change this to desired username

SET @DBuser_sql='SELECT ''?'' AS DBName,a.name AS Name,a.type_desc AS LoginType,USER_NAME(b.role_principal_id) AS AssociatedRole FROM ?.sys.database_principals a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ?.sys.database_role_members b ON a.principal_id=b.member_principal_id 
WHERE a.sid NOT IN (0x01,0x00) AND a.sid IS NOT NULL AND a.type NOT IN (''C'') AND a.is_fixed_role <> 1 AND a.name NOT LIKE ''##%'' AND ''?'' NOT IN (''master'',''msdb'',''model'',''tempdb'') ORDER BY Name'

INSERT @DBuser_table 

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command1=@DBuser_sql 

SELECT * 
  FROM @DBuser_table 
 WHERE username = @UserName
 ORDER BY DBName
```

Comment: Thank you Ferdinand, I've got this one running but can't seemed to connect all the databases from other servers that are linked together to show all the tables that a user has access to.